Starting Windows domain controller for testing in an isolated network: Can't sign in
Our backup strategy has been to export the domain controller (Hyper-V VM) along with the other server VMs to a large drive which we rotate offsite and off-grid.
Now we want to move the DC to a new server. I thought I could just export from the old and import to the new server. But when I start it up again and try to log in, it gives me this error:

We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available. Make sure your device is connected to your organization's network and try again.

We're still in test mode: I exported a snapshot of the DC, imported on the new server and used that. I pulled the network cables on the new server while starting up the DC to make sure it doesn't interfere with the existing network.
What are we doing wrong and how can we fix it?

I'm a novice at managing servers. I have a feeling I'm simply not understanding the way a domain works.

Which type of checkpoint are you using?

For AD signin to work, DNS must function as well. You don't mention how things are configured, but depending on setup this can be separate roles, or on the DC. The DHCP server of course has to point to a functioning DNS server. Additionally, do not bring up a temporary copy of a DC in a live environment; you risk a user or computer changing their password and wreaking havoc on it's account. Bring it up in isolated network environment where only test devices are present.

@GregAskew I used Powershell and didn't specify what type: Checkpoint-VM -VMName $vmName -SnapshotName $snapshotName

@vidarlo The DNS server is on the DC. Does it matter that it's offline? We can't really put it online as you mentioned

It may matter that it's not on a network. Connect it to a network hub or switch that is connected nowhere else, just so there's a network carrier; some Windows versions, without a live network connection, the entire network stack goes away which can cause this problem.

We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available. try the builtin Administrator account, those credentials are always present and cached (on a normal system at least). Or use System State backup, that always works.

"Only Production Checkpoints are supported on guests that run Active Directory Domain Services" ... probably a good reason for that. Note that production checkpoints use the same technology as system state backups. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/choose-between-standard-or-production-checkpoints-in-hyper-v

@tsc_chazz When I connected a router, it started up fine. Thanks!

@D_Bester I've reposted as an answer. Please click the check mark beside my answer; that way, anyone looking for a solution to this problem will know that an answer has been found.

With many Windows versions, when you don't have an active network, the network stack collapses, and any attempt to contact the domain controller, even when the DC is that same machine, will fail because it attempts to connect through a network stack that is not present. You don't need an Internet connection, and in this case you really don't want a connection to your in-house network, but you absolutely do need a connection to at the very least a stub network. Connect your machine via network cable to any old network switch or router that is not connected to anything else, and the network stack will be available. Logging in to the domain should then work properly.
